# Star-rating component logic implementation in react

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a star-rating component in react. I have implemented successfully the full and empty star rating but i got stuck in displaying half stars. I came up with a logic i tried many times but didn't find a way to implement that logic. Currently this component is just displaying star-ratings without any click functionality.

I want to implement this logic:

Suppose we have **selectedStars as 2.5** and **totalStars as 5** and we want to display two full stars and a half star and the rest empty stars. I separated the selectedStars into two parts one containing the integer part and other containing the floating part. I have successfully separated the two parts using

**firstHalf = Math.floor(selectedStars)** it will give as a result 2

**secondHalf = selectedStars % 1** it will give as a result 0.5

also i have converted totalStars into an array using [...Array(totalStars)] so as to represent five stars in total.
and i am running the loop on indexes.

with the both parts i want to implement this if else ladder which is as follows:

**if(index < firstHalf)** then use *font-awesome "fa fa-star"* icon

**else if(secondHalf === 0.5)** then use *font-awesome "fa fa-star-half-o"* icon and *increment secondHalf* i did this because there will be only one half star and next time when it checks for the secondHalf value the condition comes out to be false and it will move to the next statement.

**else** use *font-awesome "fa fa-star-o"* icon to represent empty stars.

I hope you understand what i want to implement here.

Comment: So what part are you looking for help with?

Comment: Implementing the if else if ladder and displaying the stars on the ui

Comment: [Check out this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/w0kk1koml8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I implemented your `secondMethod` in the [`codesandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/3ylqnv17k1) you provided:

```
secondMethod = () => {
  // implement the code for full, empty and half stars here.
  const { selectedStars, totalStars } = this.state;
  return [...Array(totalStars)].map((el, i) =>
    // check if current star should be half
    i < selectedStars && i + 1 > selectedStars ?
      <i key={i} className="fa fa-star-half-o" />
    // not half, so check if current star should be full
    : i < selectedStars ? <i key={i} className="fa fa-star" />
    // else, current star should be empty
    : <i key={i} className="fa fa-star-o" />
  );
};
```

Comment: @Sumit no prob! any time :)

Comment: Thnx again bro, your code not.only solve the pdblm but also reduces the redundant code now i can display all kinds of star only with one method.